# Pass address with Laravel's cashier newSubscription method for Stripe?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

When fetching the card with stripe, the address fields are null.

```
+"address_city": null
+"address_country": null
+"address_line1": null
+"address_line1_check": null
+"address_line2": null
+"address_state": null
+"address_zip": "49394"
+"address_zip_check": "pass"
```

This is when fetchign the card, like so

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('services.stripe.secret'));
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve('cus_**********');
$cards = $customer->sources['data'];
dd($cards[0]);
```

And here is the code I execute when they sign up to a subscription, I'm guessing this is where I need to insert or send the address information? I already gave fields for it.

```
$user->newSubscription($plan->slug, $plan->stripe_plan)->create($request->stripeToken, [
    'email' => $user->email,
]);
```